# Visualizing budget "burn-down" where overages can happen

Tags: info-visualisation

I'm looking at a dashboard component that displays how much of the allotted budget has been used up in a project. What are some ways of visually summarizing this that take into account for overages?

e.g., $1000 has been budgeted, but the current cost is running over $1000. Overages are bad and need to be highlighted to the user so they can take action.

Answer (score 1):

Bar Graphs would work here. You can signify overages by having a column specific for over budget calculations.

I found http://baansconsulting.com/?p=1471 to be a good representation how to depict over budget items while displaying what the budget was initially.

Additional chart variations that can be done in excel can be found here - http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/04/05/budget-vs-actual-charts/. These could also be used in a dashboard format.

In this example, a dial is used to gauge budget - http://help.senior-systems.com/images/OBMDash.png

I found these by performing the Google Image Search - "graph over budget dashboard"